# How are application like twitter implemented?

Tags: algorithm, twitter

Suppose A follows 100 person,

then will need 100 join statement,

which is horrible for database I think.

Or there are other ways ?

Comment: No, you don't need 100 joins, because you *should not have one table per person*. Google "database normalization".

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm?

Comment: I can't explain the concept of DB normalisation in 1 comment, but basically: every table should represent a class or kind of object, and every row within that table should describe an instance of that kind of object, including a field or fields whose values uniquely identify that row (the "primary key"). Many-to-many relationships (e.g. between tweeters and followers) are implemented with a 3rd table that records pairs of IDs from the other two tables. You then only need a join between two/three tables, depending on exactly what you want to see.

Comment: @j_random_hacker ,it's kind of moving N*M process from user to database,right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly sorry Shore. Really it is worth your while to read up on DB normalisation -- it's not as hard as it looks and will make a few things much clearer. There are many good tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you need 100 Joins?

You would have a simple table "Follows" with your ID and the other persons ID in it...

Then you retrieve the "Tweets" by joining something like this:

```
Select top 100 
    tweet.* 
from 
    tweet 
inner join 
    followers on follower.id = tweet.AuthorID 
where 
    followers.masterID = yourID
```

Now you just need a decent caching and make sure you use a non locking query and you have all information... (Well maybe add some userdata into the mix)

Edit:

tweet

```
ID - tweetid
AuthorID - ID of the poster
```

Followers

```
MasterID - (Basically your ID)
FollowerID - (ID of the person following you)
```

The `Followers` table has a composite ID based on master and `followerID`
It should have 2 indexes - one on "masterID - followerID" and one on "FollowerID and MasterID"

Comment: +1, it's worth noting that this is a classic N-to-M relation, and the standard solution is a link table like you describe.

Comment: what's the solution for N*M*M relation then?

Comment: whats N-M-M? Please decribe

The above table can be used in both directions. 
Say column 1 is master and 2 is follower.. so a row 1-2 means user 2 follows user one, and 2-1 means that user 1 follows user 2...

Comment: You "only" have a relation between 2 tabels. So n-m-m would be implemented as n-m and m-m (which could also be called an extension table - assuming the 2 M's are allways identical)

Answer (score 1):

The real trick is to minimize your database usage (e.g., cache, cache, cache) and to understand usage patterns. In the specific case of Twitter, they use a bunch of different techniques from queuing, an insane amount of in-memory caching, and some really clever data flow optimizations.  Give [Scaling Twitter: Making Twitter 10000 percent faster](http://highscalability.com/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster) and the other associated articles a read. Your question about how you implement "following" is to denormalize the data (precalculate and maintain join tables instead of performing joins on the fly) or **[don't use a database at all](http://jens.mooseyard.com/2007/04/twitter-rails-hammers-and-11000-nails-per-second/)**. <-- *Make sure to read this!*

Comment: Interesting link but I'm -1ing this since it's *way too soon* to start worrying about denormalising for scalability reasons -- the OP doesn't even know what a normalised DB is! Do you really think performance is top priority here? Please put a disclaimer at the top saying "When your site has 1 million active users, you should maybe think about considering the following."

Comment: The OP did ask how an application like Twitter is implemented?  I agree that it is overkill in this case.  We have run into scaling problems with considerably fewer than one million users - 10000 or so client requests per second can cause problems if your processing requires more than just fetch a few rows and return them.

Comment: Sure, 1 million users was just a wild guess. If you put your more realistic estimate in a disclaimer at the top I'll happily +1.